# 3 linearly- independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove by counter-example:

${v_1,v_2,v_3}$ linearly-dependent $\Rightarrow$ $ {v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_2+v_3}$ are linearly-dependent.

tried to find a counter example and couldn't so I tried to prove but again I get nowhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly dependent, then for some $a,b,c$ not all zero we have $av_1+bv_2+cv_3=0$.

Hence $\frac{1}{2}(a+b-c)(v_1+v_2)+\frac{1}{2}(a-b+c)(v_1+v_3)+\frac{1}{2}(-a+b+c)(v_2+v_3)=av_1+bv_2+cv_3=0$, so $v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_2+v_3$ are linearly dependent.

Note that $a+b-c,a-b+c,-a+b+c$ cannot all be zero, because then the sum of the first two $2a$ would be zero and hence $a$ would be zero, and similarly $b,c$.

Comment: but, but,,,,how did you come up with that combo? is it that trivial?

Comment: Put $\lambda(v_1+v_2)+\mu(v_1+v_3)+\nu(v_2+v_3)=av_1+bv_2+cv_3$ and solve for $\lambda,\mu,\nu$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$To say that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly dependent means that the subspace $\Span{v_1,v_2,v_3}$ generated by them has dimension less than three. Now $\Span{a + b ,b+ c, c + a} \subseteq \Span{v_1,v_2,v_3} $.

An alternative, direct approach is the following. To say that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly dependent means that there is a nonzero row vector $\theta  = [\alpha, \beta, \gamma]$ such that the formal product
$$
\theta \cdot \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3 \end{bmatrix} = 0.
$$
Now we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}v_1+v_2\\v_2+v_3\\v_3+v_1\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}   v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
so that, taking an inverse matrix
$$
\frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -1\\
-1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}v_1+v_2\\v_2+v_3\\v_3+v_1\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix},$$
and thus
$$
 \theta \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -1\\
-1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}  v_1+v_2\\v_2+v_3\\v_3+v_1\end{bmatrix}
=
[\alpha+\beta-\gamma,
-\alpha+\beta+\gamma,\alpha-\beta+\gamma]
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix} v_1+v_2\\v_2+v_3\\v_3+v_1  \end{bmatrix} = 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you can recover the original $3$ linearly independent vectors by linear combinations of the new set of vectors, they must also be linearly independent.

So $(v_1+v_2) + (v_1+v_3) -(v_2+v_3) = 2v_1$ and similarly for $v_2$ and $v_3$ shows the linear independence of the revised set.

Similarly if $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly dependent, the above recovery process shows that the new set of vectors is also linearly dependent to the same degree - the space spanned by the new combination vector set is the same as the space spanned by the original three. But more generally, we can't introduce linear independence by linear combinations of a linearly dependent set, otherwise the original set of vectors would be linearly independent.